Turning Antarctica green with volcanism
As the title suggests, i am wondering if it is possible to turn Antarctica green with volcanism, minimizing the effects on other parts of the planet.
What I have in mind is an extensive volcanic system in the heart of Antarctica that warms up the central areas of the continent (ideally up to tropical levels). The farthest you go from this system, the colder it gets, until the rim of this Antarctica is as cold as it's real life counterpart.
Would such a thing be possible? And if not, in what alternative ways could this be achieved?

"minimizing the effects on other parts of the planet" depends on your definition of "minimizing". If you mean "rest of the planet probably won't notice" - I'm pretty sure not possible. If you mean "reduce the devastation on the rest of the planet from probably-catastrophic to still-probably-catastrophic-but-slightly-less levels" then - yeah, likely doable. But I'd assume that the difference brought by this minimization is negligible.

On another note, I don't see how this is a [[tag:worldbuilding-process]] question.

There are already active volcanoes in the antarctic. I would expect that if there are enough active volcanoes to warm the Antarctic it would be via C02 sufficient to globally warm the Earth. That is local warming won't happen without global warming.

If much of the Antarctic ice melted, there would be an inland sea surrounded by the remaining ice, and very little mountaintops above the water level.  If much of the Antarctic ice evaporated, it would eventually condense as rain or snow, and eventually end up in the oceans, raising sea levels significantely.

Massive volcanism is usually correlated with the emission of huge amount of gases which are not usually happily related to life, like SO2 or CO2.
Secondary volcanism, heating up rocks and water, might help getting rid of the ice and increase the temperatures in a limited area.
However your would be left with the challenge given by the prolonged nights, which would severely limit the kind of plants which would be able to grow.
With that there is no volcanism which can help.

Thanks! By secondary volcanism do you mean things like the caldera in Yellowstone creating geothermal vents?

Part of the reason for the current cold in Antartica is due to how there is open ocean surrounding it. When the Drake Passage opened up, it allowed the Antarctic Circumpolar Current to increase which cut off Antartica from heat. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_Passage
So, one way to have volcanism heat up Antartica is to have a line of volcanoes going up from Antartica to South America cutting off that current. That could allow more heat from the equator to get down there.
One challenge with turning Antartica green is that much of the current bedrock is below sea level. (See the image at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geology_of_Antarctica.) It could rebound above sea level, but that is unknown as to when.
